# How many different representations of pi can we come up with?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Let me explain: a friend of a friend is opening a new pizza restaurant called "Pi", and he's looking to decorate his walls with pi-related material: formulas, equations, theorems w/ proof, diagrams, etc.  Any suggestion is welcome, so long as it meets these two criteria:

1. It has to be mathematically correct.
2. It has to be either a representation of pi itself or lead directly to a representation of pi.

So for example, this is okay: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ (because it equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$)
But this is not: $\frac{22}{7}$.

How many can we come up with?

Comment: There are 158 of them listed [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/Pi/)...

Comment: I'm not totally convinced that this is appropriate for MO, and I imagine it'd be less controversial at someplace like Art of Problem Solving. But at a bare minimum this should be community wiki.

Comment: Well, it's not 158... the list includes things like the formula for the absolute value of $\pi$ (!)

Comment: This sounds like a fun question, that could perhaps (slightly) help somebody out in the real world.  +1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have run its course

Answer (score 10):

Let me suggest getting a striped floor and tiling it with randomly placed needles.

Comment: Try explaining *that* to the health inspectors...

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal expansion of $\pi$: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBPFormula.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, Mathworld does list a bunch of formulas. Some of them are more mathematically interesting than others (BBP, Ramanujan's, $\zeta(2)$), but purely aesthetically they're probably all about the same.

One thing that Mathworld doesn't list that could be interesting is [Buffon's needle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%2527s_needle). I'm not sure how you'd represent it statically, but it's easy to understand and surprising, which is a good combination for a lay audience.

Comment: Here are links to <a href="http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Representations+of+Pi">Representations of Pi</a> and <a href="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html">Pi Formulas</a>.


Answer (score 1):

I was reminded of this classic a few days ago: $\pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + \ldots$

Is there a slick proof of this (in particular one that avoids discussing arctan for a long time)?

Comment: Slicker that this <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_pi#Elementary_argument>?

Comment: That works - I didn't click through far enough in Wikipedia when I went to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#History
Thanks for the link! 

Comment: Beware! <http://xkcd.com/214/> :)

Answer (score 1):

I really like this formula:
$1+\frac{1}{1\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5} + \frac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7} + \frac{1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9} + \cdots + {{1\over 1 + {1\over 1 + {2\over 1 + {3\over 1 + {4\over 1 +                                     {5\over 1 + \cdots }}}}}}} = \sqrt{\frac{e\cdot\pi}{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 16 of Jorg Arndt and Christoph Haenel, $\pi$ Unleashed, is called $\pi$ Formula Collection, and has well over 100 formulas. Another source is Pierre Eymard and Jean-Pierre Lafon, The Number $\pi$, published by the American Math Society.